# Bundler raindrops dependency issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I've been having problems with dependencies for a while now, and although I generally manually overcome these, I would like to understand the correct way to resolve such dependencies. My idea till now has been to just get it to work somehow, but would love to know about how knowledgable people do this..

So, my latest problem is this..

```
    You have already activated raindrops 0.8.0, but your Gemfile requires raindrops 0.10.0
```

In my gemfile, I have raindrops (0.10.0), as well as grouped with unicorn (4.2) as raindrops (0.7.0)

My current gemfile is here https://gist.github.com/3103422

Would be great to know what is the best way to solve these problems...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding you but the "best way" to resolve dependency issues is to let bundler handle it for you. That's the whole reason it was created. Doing it "manually" might be good for understanding what is going on but it's not something you want to be doing normally. It just becomes a huge time sink and you end up wrestling with dependency resolution rather than focusing on solving your original problem.

The basic idea is to have a `Gemfile` with the gems you use. Then run `bundle install` and let bundler resolve the dependencies. Here's the [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) website.

Comment: Hey @Dty ... yes that's how I do it all the time..but in some cases the gemspec states different dependencies that cause issues. And in this particular case, I'm actually not doing nothing apart from just doing a bundle install. Can't seem to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think we need to see your Gemfile too (as opposed to your Gemfile.lock)